# Determine conservative vector field and find gradient vector field.

Tags: linear-algebra, indefinite-integrals

Let $F(x,y) = e^y \mathbf{i} + xe^y \mathbf{j}$. Determine whether or not $F$ is a conservative vector field. If it is, find a function $f$ such that $\nabla f = F$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have found that
let P = e^y
let Q = xe^y

dP/dy = dQ/dx = e^y and that it is a conservative vector field. How to I continue from here?

Comment: In order to find $f$ integrate $P(x,y)=e^y$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: with function P or Q?

Comment: You can also integrate $Q(x,y)=xe^y$ with respect to $y$.

Comment: Ok, I integrate P with respect to x to obtain xe^y + g(y).
Differentiating that with respect to y will give me xe^y + g`(y).
Comparing to Q, it gives me g`(y) = 0?

Comment: It just says that $g(y)=C$ a constant

Comment: so grad f = xe^y + C? or just grad f = xe^y?

Comment: Both of them... $f$ is not unique!

Comment: in that case grad f = xe^y + C? Since C can be 0